# How to serialize async pthreads code sections

Tags: multithreading, synchronization, pthreads, semaphore

I have a number of pre-emptive (asynchronous) threads (TA) that want temporary access to a shared resource. This would a typical use for a `pthread_mutex`.

However, I have a few things that make this more complicated:

- I have little control over the complete code because I'm providing only a set of functions to facilitate the procedure.
- There are a set of "main" threads (TM), over which I have little control, and that use a private mutex to access said shared resource. They use a private scheduler that manages these threads, in such a way that only one is allowed to run at any time, effectively having these threads run cooperatively.
- Any of these main threads (TM) may cause the async threads (TA) to run. That's all part of the programmer's code to whom I want to provide the extra functions.

I have to wait for those TM threads to be in a "safe" state where I can then allow the TA threads to access the shared resource. I have a way to do that.

The idea is therefore to suspend (block) all the TA threads until that safe state is reached in any one of the TM threads, then suspend that TM thread, allow each of the TA threads to run one after the other, and resume the TM thread once they're all done.

When the TM threads reach said safe state, my function `shared_resource_is_safe()` will be called.

Also, the programmer will have to invoke my functions `acquire_access()` and `surrender_access()` before and after accessing the shared resource.

So I have three functions to implement, and I am struggling with using mutexes and / or semaphores to achieve my goal.

Here's what I've come up with so far:

```
dispatch_semaphore_t semaphore;
pthread_mutex_t mutex;
int is_safe = 0;

void setup_once() {
    semaphore = dispatch_semaphore_create (0);
    pthread_mutex_init (&mutex, NULL);
}

void acquire_access() {
    pthread_mutex_lock (&mutex);
    dispatch_semaphore_wait (semaphore, DISPATCH_TIME_FOREVER);
    assert(is_safe);
}

void surrender_access() {
    pthread_mutex_unlock (&mutex);
}

void shared_resource_is_safe() {
    // this shall resume thread that's called acquire_access()
    is_safe = 1;
    while (dispatch_semaphore_signal (semaphore) != 0) {
        // Wait until the signaled thread
        // has called surrender_access()
        pthread_mutex_lock (&mutex);
        pthread_mutex_unlock (&mutex);
    }
    is_safe = 0;
}
```

The semaphore is used to have any thread calling `acquire_access()` to wait for `shared_resource_is_safe()`.

The mutex shall make sure that every async threads waits for `shared_resource_is_safe()` allowing it to run.

This does not work reliably, though. I run into cases where the assertion for `is_safe` fails in the async threads, meaning the main thread does not wait for the async thread(s) to call `surrender_access()`. What do I do wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer by mevets identifies your bug.  As mentioned, you can solve this with condition variables:

```
pthread_mutex_t mutex = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;
pthread_cond_t cond_safe = PTHREAD_COND_INITIALIZER;
pthread_cond_t cond_waiters = PTHREAD_COND_INITIALIZER;
int is_safe = 0;
long waiters = 0;

void acquire_access(void)
{   
    pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);
    waiters++;
    while (!is_safe)
        pthread_cond_wait(&cond_safe, &mutex);
}

void surrender_access(void)
{   
    waiters--;
    if (!waiters)
        pthread_cond_signal(&cond_waiters);
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);
}

void shared_resource_is_safe(void)
{   
    pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);
    if (waiters)
    {
        is_safe = 1;
        pthread_cond_broadcast(&cond_safe);
        while (waiters)
            pthread_cond_wait(&cond_waiters, &mutex);
        is_safe = 0;
    }
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);
}
```

Comment: If `acquire_access` is called before `shared_resource_is_safe`, the former shall wait for the latter, but with both acquiring the mutex, this won't work, I suppose. (and feel free to delete your "fixed" comment now that it's cleared up)

Comment: @ThomasTempelmann: No, that's fine - `pthread_cond_wait()` atomically releases the mutex and waits (then re-acquires the mutex before returning).

Comment: This method works as long as shared_resource_is_safe() is called only from a single "main" thread. But as soon as different main threads call it, cooperatively (alternatingly), I get a deadlock. That's why I tried to use the semaphore: It was not tied to a particular thread, but mutexes are. I wonder if I should create a short test program so that this can be tested better (my current test uses said foreign system that I cannot share for testing easily).

Comment: @ThomasTempelmann: There should be no deadlock, but if two threads can call `shared_resource_is_safe()` at the same time then you'll need to change the `pthread_cond_signal()` of `cond_waiters` to a `pthread_cond_broadcast()`, otherwise some callers to `shared_resource_is_safe()` could get stuck on the `pthread_cond_wait()`.

Comment: Indeed. I think I must have made a mistake originally, as my actual code is a bit more complex. Now it seems to work as intended. Thanks a lot, as I'd never have figured this out myself.

Answer (score 2):

when dispatch_semaphore_signal() returns 0 ( to indicate there is nobody waiting upon it ), it has incremented the semaphore, thus the next dispatch_semaphore_wait() will acquire the semaphore without waiting.

What you want is a condition variable, which dispatch doesn’t provide.   It is possible to construct one using the semaphore [ie. keep a separate counter of 
how many to wake up protected by the mutex ], but at this point you might want to consider if you aren’t digging a deeper hole.

Dispatch was designed with a specific model in mind, and you seem to be working to subvert that.   Is there perhaps a way to get the effect you want in another way?